# Vcard does not import on android

Tags: android, ios, swift, vcf-vcard

Hi guys i have been working on application in iOS Swift that exports a vcard that can/should be imported on iPhone and android. For iPhone the vcard works perfectly but for android the vcard does not import. I used the following code to do that. Please have a look and let me know what i am doing wrong.

```
func textBasedVCard()-> Data?{

let imageString = self.imageData.base64EncodedString()
var string = "BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:3.0\n"
string += "N:\(self.name!);\nFN:\(self.name!)\nORG:\(self.company!)\nTITLE:\(self.title!)\nTEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:\(self.phone!)\nADR;TYPE=WORK:;;\(self.address!)\nNOTE:\(self.notes!)\nitem1.URL:\(self.web!)\nitem2.URL:\(self.blog!)\nitem3.URL:\(self.socialMedia1!)\nitem4.URL:\(self.socialMedia2!)\nitem5.URL:\(self.socialMedia3!)\nEMAIL;TYPE=PREF,INTERNET:\(self.email!)\nPHOTO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=JPEG:\(imageString)\nEND:VCARD"
print(string)
let utf8str = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
//utf8str?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
if let base64Encoded = utf8str?.base64EncodedString(options: .init(rawValue: 0))
{
    return Data(base64Encoded: base64Encoded)!

}
return nil
}
```

Comment: can you show me vcard file print screen?

Comment: Vcard file print screen?

Comment: I dont understand.

Comment: your generated vcard file Means String Print Screen

Comment: How should i send you that here?